# Storing Variables to Memory Swift

Tags: swift, iphone, memory, battery

Ive got an app that collects data from an api and does some calculations to that data and assigns it to a variable. It all gets triggered when the phone is plugged into a charge, and when the phone is unplugged again i want it to drop that number into a variable and store it to memory so that the variabler remains the same when i open the app a second time.

i build and run the app on my physical device, the only problem is that as soon as i close the app i loose all the old data (even though i never "rebuild" the app). in my mind this could be one of two reasons:

1. this is just not possible in the way the compiler is built, ie it doesnt ever store data like that and is functioning as expected
2. im declaring the varible wrong somehow?

i declare it as `var startCharge : Float = 0` and `var endCharge : Float = 0` and for the battery i got

```
var chargingVar = ""
    var batteryLevel: Float {
          return UIDevice.current.batteryLevel
      }
```

then i let the phone look for when its getting charged and do stuff

```
func batteryStateChanged(){
        if (UIDevice.current.batteryState == .charging) {
            UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
            self.chargingVar = "Charging \u{1F603}"
                 chargingAlert()
                getData()
                startCharge = batteryLevel
          }else{
            self.chargingVar = "Not Charging \u{1F622} "
                 chargingAlert()
                setLastValue()
                endCharge = batteryLevel
        }
```

finally i want to drop this into a "static" variable :P that does change when i close and reopen the app `let savedCharge = endCharge - startCharge` but this is where it all drops. Please help.

Comment: If you want to store a value or state between sessions you should use UserDefaults or some other persistence method like a file or Core Data but in this case UserDefaults is probably the best option.

Comment: UserDefaults! i figured it was something like that i was missing. im going to try it out and get back here with findings and issues :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i first declared the variable as:

```
var startCharge : Double = 0
var lastCharge : Double = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "lastCharge")
```

and then in the function just set the variables in the function

```
startCharge = batteryLevel
endCharge = batteryLevel

UserDefaults.standard.set(lastCharge, forKey: "lastCharge")
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can easily save/store the data in UserDefault as following:-**

```
  let savedCharge = endCharge - startCharge
  UserDefaults.standard.set(savedCharge, forKey: "chargeData")
  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

**Retrieve data anywhere it's a requirement throughout the app as following:-**

```
  var savedChargeData: String? = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "chargeData") as? String
```

**Also, you can remove data by using their key as following:-**

```
  UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "chargeData")
  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```